# How to intercept CXF webservice logging?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf

How can I intercept CXF logging to cross out some digits during logging (banking + credit card information basically).

I use the following for log4j automated logging:

```
    Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
    client.getInInterceptors().add(new LoggingInInterceptor());
    client.getOutInterceptors().add(new LoggingOutInterceptor());
```

What would I have to change so that can adapt soap xml requests and delete some values before they are logged?

Comment: Here is a complete implementation for filtering: https://github.com/greenbird/xml-formatter-components/tree/master/cxf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using custom log interceptor, where you can process the message.

```
public class CustLogInInterceptor extends AbstractSoapInterceptor {


    public CustLogInInterceptor() {
        super(Phase.RECEIVE);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(SoapMessage message) throws Fault {

        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) message.get ( AbstractHTTPDestination.HTTP_REQUEST );
        LoggerUtil.setLog(CustLogInInterceptor.class , LogConstants.DEBUG, "Request From the address : " + httpRequest.getRemoteAddr ( ) );

        try
        {
            //Handle you custom code add log it
              LoggerUtil.setLog(CustLogInInterceptor.class , LogConstants.DEBUG, "Log here" );
        }

        catch ( Exception ex )
        {
            ex.printStackTrace ( );
        }



    }

}
```

Your CXF configuration would look like something like below

```
<jaxws:endpoint>

    <jaxws:inInterceptors>
           <ref bean="custInterceptor"/>
        </jaxws:inInterceptors>

</jaxws:endpoint>

<bean id="custInterceptor" class="com.kp.CustLogInInterceptor">
```

Answer (score 2):

The CXF logging interceptors have a method:

```
protected String transform(String originalLogString) {
    return originalLogString;
}
```

that can be overridden to do any sort of obfuscation or something else that may be required.   Just create subclasses and override that method.